# Multi Tenancy in Microsoft bot framework webchat

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have successfully hosted an instance of microsoft's Botframework web chat using directline on public domain, I want to make  a chatbot in such a way that my customers can have their own channels completely separated from each other and I cannot find any kind of documentation anywhere, Kindly suggest me if this is possible and how?

I have  written the complete code in Node.js and have very less idea about c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no such feature for uniform customized chat channel in bot framework. So we can leverage `new builder.Message().address(address)` to send messages to specific users from the official sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages/simpleSendMessage/index.js.

So I had a quick test which will save the users' addresses into an address list in server memory as a `"customize channel"`, and trigger a key work to send message to these addresses in list as a broadcast in this `"customize channel"`:

```
let channel_address = [];
bot.dialog('joinChannel',(session)=>{
    channel_address.push(session.message.address);
}).triggerAction({
    matches:/join/i
})

bot.dialog('broadcast',(session)=>{
    channel_address.forEach((address)=>{
        bot.send(
            new builder.Message(session).address(address).text(session.message.text)
        )
    })
}).triggerAction({
    matches:/^broadcast: .*/
})
```

Test Step:

- Open two emulators connect to your local bot
- in both emulators, type `"join"`
- in either emulator, type text like `broadcast: hi there`
  [image]